# Como puedo generar un pdf con jasperReport desde el controller?

Tags: java, jsp, spring, jasper-reports

apenas empiezo en esto y no se como implementar un pdf, estoy utilizando spring mvc, ya tengo un formato hecho con iReport, ahora lo que quiero es visualizarlo en mi jsp para que pueda descargarlo, pero como lo hago?

Alguien tiene un código que pueda usar para implementarlo y mandarlo a llamar desde mi controlador?
Quiero que al dar click en un botón de mi jsp pueda visualizar mi formato y si quiero que se descargue

Solo agregué este código que me dijeron que me ayudaría, pero no se que siga después, ojala me puedan ayudar

```html
@Bean
public  JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver(){

JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jasperreports");
resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
resolver.setOrder(1);

return resolver;



}
```

Comment: ¿De dónde te has sacado ese código? ¿Es de este artículo: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/04/spring-mvc-generar-reportes.html?

Comment: Al parecer si es ese codigo